# Как хранить float числа в mysql?

Tags: mysqli

Есть число, например `100.00000098562` также число может быть целым, например `150`

Главное не должно быть никакого округления, есть float и decimal, но не понятно какие числа они могут хранить, ничего не нашел про ограничения

Какой тип поля нужно выбрать в mysql?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Comment: @entithat поля с типом float я тут почитал что нельзя хранить float числа, там что то с неточностью связано

Comment: Если надо хранить точное число - используется DECIMAL. Если пределы на количество цифр у DECIMAL не позволяют сохранить точное значение - используется VARCHAR.